# Nginx doesnt loaded web page

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

i configured nginx and after building docker image and run sudo `docker-compose up`
it has no error, but the problem is web server with given host doenst loaded:

```
Unable to connect

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:4200.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the web.
```

i have defined nginx.conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;  # Angular service
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;  # Django service
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

and also Dockerfile for it :

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

docker-compose for nginx:

```
nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: auralab-nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      # - angular
      - django
```

i tryed both to put my actual server ip in proxy pass but doesnt work, its `34.159.204.45`
any  sollutions ?

Comment: How is the post related to GCP? --- How is the post related to programming?

Comment: yeah, its about nginx

Comment: This does not answer any of the two questions.

Comment: You need to forward to the internal address of the docker host. See [here (`github.com`)](https://github.com/chehl/chameleon/blob/main/localdeployment/nginx/default.conf#L5) and [here (`github.com`)](https://github.com/chehl/chameleon/blob/main/localdeployment/docker-compose.yml#L69) for an example.

Comment: It looks like you're pointing your browser at `http://localhost:4200` (from the Firefox error message), but your Nginx server is published on port 80 (first Compose `ports:` number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The localhost address points to the container itself.
Instead of using:

`proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;`

use:

`proxy_pass http://angular:4200;`

Where angular is service name, like nginx from docker-compose file